# AJAX not sending current value of selected option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

php code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
$file_handle = fopen('my_file.json', 'w');
fwrite($file_handle, json_encode($_POST['data']));
fclose($file_handle);
}
?>
```

html

```
<h1 id="title" class="text-lg-center text-md-center text-sm-left mb-4">test 
title</h1>
<p class="lead text-lg-center text-md-center text-sm-left mb-4">test 
content</p>
<button id="test" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline- 
success">Publish List</button>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
<select class="form-control" id="selectfont">
</select>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$(function () {
var font = 0;
var font_names = ["Montez","Lobster","Josefin Sans"];

$.each(font_names , function (index , value) {
    $('<option />' , {
        'value' : index,
        'text' : value
    })
    .css({'font-family' : font_names[index]})
    .appendTo("#selectfont");
});

$("#selectfont").change(function () {
    var font = $(this).val();
    $("p").css('font-family' , font_names[font]);
});

var htmldata = {
    'content_font_type': font_names[font],
    'content_font_size': parseFloat($("title").css('font-size'))
    };

$("#test").click( function(){
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: {data: htmldata},
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
});
```

so what i want to ask is why in my_file.json the **content_font_type** and **content_font_size** not changing, but when i use alert() function in **$("#selectfont").change** it show correctly. Also, success always return empty when i use console.log and alert()

Comment: did yu check the file  permission . did yu test to run the php alone and see any error?  and may try giving a different var name for data !

Comment: You should be able to debug this from developer tools, network tab.  Check the request and response for your ajax there.

Comment: @zod , i already try everything you mentioned, but still not working

Comment: @James , request and response seem good to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. When `#selectfont` changes, you're setting a local variable `font`, not the global variable, because you re-declare it with `var font`. Get rid of the `var` keyword.
2. You're setting `htmldata` when the page first loads. You need to set it when the user clicks on the button, so you get the updated values.

You don't really need the `font` variable at all. You can get the value of `#selectfont` when you're setting `htmldata`.

```
$("#test").click( function(){
    var htmldata = {
        'content_font_type': font_names[$("#selectfont").val()],
        'content_font_size': parseFloat($("title").css('font-size'))
    };
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: {data: htmldata},
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: that really help me, thank you, with that explanation it really help me understanding that problem